# Why does this property remain nil after initialization?

Tags: swift

I have a `CollectionViewCell` :

```
 import UIKit

  class NetworkButtonCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var networkAction: NetworkAction! <-- This property is always nil for some reason
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    init(networkAction: NetworkAction) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.networkAction = networkAction
        configure()
    }

    
    private func configure() {

        
        switch networkAction {
        case .post:
            print("POST")
        case .get:
            print("GET")
        case .delete:
            print("DELETE")
        case .update:
            print("UPDATE")
        default:
            print("Nothing") //< -- This is always called
        }
        
    }
}
```

And the cell is being initialized inside of a initializer for `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`:

```
private func configureDataSource() {
    dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, NetworkButton>(collectionView: collectionView, cellProvider: { collectionView, indexPath, button in
        
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "reuseID", for: indexPath) as! NetworkButtonCollectionViewCell
            cell.networkAction = button.networkAction //<-- This should prevent the property from being nil
            print(cell.networkAction)
            return cell
        })
    }
```

EDIT Adding a relevant function:

```
    private func updateSnapshot() {
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, NetworkButton>()
    snapshot.appendSections([.all])
    snapshot.appendItems([
        NetworkButton(networkAction: .post), NetworkButton(networkAction: .get), NetworkButton(networkAction: .delete), NetworkButton(networkAction: .update)
    ], toSection: .all)
        self.dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a breakpoint inside the `configure()` method where you are seeing it is `nil`. It will show you the stack trace - where the call came from.

When you are asking the collectionView to dequeue a cell for an `indexPath`, it instantiates the cell which should invoke following.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configure() // networkAction has NOT been initialized at this point
}
```

Comment: Setting breakpoints up shows me that my custom initializer is not being called.. which I am trying to understand why now

Comment: @SergioBost In case this answered your original question - why is it nil - please consider accepting this.